# WordPress Plugin Permissions

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently writing a WordPress plugin and I am having trouble getting the permissions to work correctly

```
    function submitPageActions(){
    add_posts_page('Page Submission', 'Page Submission', 1, 'Page Submission', 'submitpage_form');
    }
```

I am using that to add a button to the post menu, and I would like it to be acessable for Contributor and above. But, even when logged in with the Admin account I get

> "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the usage is `add_posts_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);` where $capability is a string.  For a full reference have a look at the [Capabilities Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities) but 'publish_posts' is probably what you want.

Comment: I tried to put published_posts but it still gave me the same error... I will try it on another WordPress install to see if It is just this install.

Comment: how are you calling submitPageActions(), with `add_action('admin_menu', 'submitPageActions');` ?

Comment: Also your slug should be something like 'my-page-submission' as it's possible that the spaces in the string are breaking something too.

Comment: yes I am calling the method with that syntax... I will change the slug and see what that does.

Comment: GOT IT! It was the slug! Thanks.